# AngularJS Form With Dates in Different Time Zone Than the Browser's Time Zone

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a form for booking appointments:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input type="date" ng-model="scheduled" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Time:</label>
    <input type="time" ng-model="scheduled" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Summary: {{scheduled}}
  </div>
</form>
```

This form appears to be automatically scoped to the browser's time zone. For example, if I set the date and time to **2016-03-03** and **12:00 AM** respectively the appointment's scheduled is set to **2016-03-03T08:00:00.000Z** (when the system clock is in PST).

I'm now interested in modifying the form to allow for setting an arbitrary time zone (based on the office - but for simplicity from a dropdown will work):

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>TZ:</label>
    <select ng-model="tz">
      <option value="pst">PST</option>
      <option value="est">EST</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ...
  <div>
    Summary: {{scheduled | date : 'medium' : tz}} {{tz}}
  </div>
</form>
```

This changes the display to be in the selected time zone but does not change the input. How can I change the time zone of the form based on the option?